# How does function params influence gas cost?

Tags: solidity

Let's suppose I have a function:

```js
    function doSomething(bytes memory _data){
    ...

}
```

How does the gas cost increase given the size of the function param _data?
Does it has a limit on how big _data can be?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

check out this link http://www.scs.stanford.edu/18au-cs251/lectures/lecture10.pdf

In this lecture by Stanford, it says that **the more the arguments, the more gas it consumes.**

Comment: I want to know based on the size of a single argument, not many arguemnts. But that helps too!